# Adding large data sets within a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, store, addition

I'm attempting to make a very basic gating system, however the smallest data I have is single cycle which equals a **18*100** array. I've attempted just plotting it with a *hold on/off* function and collecting the data after with a `h=findobj(gca,'Type','line');`. However this takes forever and requires a lot of reshaping. Is there a simpler way to either store the data or add the complete arrays (not sum as that does line by line which is a no-no) together in the for loop?

```
h=findobj(gca,'Type','line'); %data retrieved from orginal figure
x=get(h,'Xdata');
y=get(h,'Ydata');
X=reshape(x,(18),[]);
Y=reshape(y,(18),[]);

hold on
    for i=1:4;
     xx=X(:,i);
     yy=Y(:,i);
     gx=cell2mat(xx); 
     gy=cell2mat(yy); 
    plot(gx) % manipulated data from orginal figure, 
    plot(gy) % plot required to extract all the for loop data
    end
hold off
```

Basically I just want to add the four `gx` together and divide them, however they have to be added as bulk, not line by line as one cycle of the loop equals a cycle of the system. (Also the 4 is just a number it really is more like 60+, which is why I can't just do it manually).

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to sum up the `gx`s together, why not do this - `sum(cell2mat(X),2)` and similarly for `gy`s? But then you won't be able to plot individual `gx` and `gy`.

Comment: This is really unclear, please could you clarify?. "added as bulk" doesn't make sense to me.  You mean you have a bunch of matrices which are `18 x 100` and you want to sum them to equal another `18 x 100` matrix? Why do you need to get your data out of the figure, don't you already have it and if not how are you putting it into the figure in the first place?

Comment: Sum(cell2mat(X),2) doesn't work as it can't be a 1*18 array which it makes. Basically i'm extracting the data from a simulation of  a ball bouncing. And comparing the bounce cycle at each bounce. Each bounce cycle is a 18 x 100 matrix, and has too stay that size. The aim is to get the original extracted matrix n x 18 x 100, separate it into 18 x 100 matrices add the 18 x 100 together and then divide by n, getting a 'standard' 18 x 100 bounce. The 18 x 100 is required for my re-plotting of the simulation.

Comment: This but for a n>50; 
    SX=(cell2mat(X(:,1))+cell2mat(X(:,2))+cell2mat(X(:,3))+cell2mat(X(:,4)))/4
So i'd need a for loop to do it, and thats were I fail